# jquery catch event from a generated element

Tags: javascript, jquery, listener

I am getting data from AJAX to build a table.  This table will have a link to delete a row from the database.  I'm having trouble getting a listener to respond to a click on the generated content's "remove" link.

```
<!-- contribId is populated initially from PHP -->
<input id="hidden-contrib-id" value="<?= $contribId ?>" />

<div id="checksEnteredContainer">
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  // get data via ajax and build table
  buildCheckEnteredTable($('#hidden-contrib-id').val());

  // various listeners here...

  $('.remove_check').on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).data('contribution-id'));
  });

});

/**
 * Get checks from database
 */
function buildCheckEnteredTable(contribId) {
  var url = "/path/to/script";
  var response = $.post(url, {action: 'getChecks', contribId: contribId});

  response.done(function(result) {

    // build html table from the data
    $('#checksEnteredContainer').html(buildTable(result));
}

function buildTable(data) {
  var numberOfRows = data.length;
  var rows='';
  for(i=0; i<numberOfRows; ++i) {
    rows += '<tr>' + 
            '<td>' + data[i].checkNumber + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + data[i].amount + '</td>' + 
            '<td><a href="#" class="remove_check" data-contribution-id="' + data[i].checkId + '">remove</a></td>'
            '</tr>';
  }

  var table = '<table class="table"><tr><th>Check Number</th><th>Amount</th><th></th></tr>' + 
              rows + 
              '</table>';

  return table;
}
```

The table creation is working fine and displaying in the browser; what's not working is the listener for `remove_check` class.

My guess is that the newly-created table is not actually in the DOM and the listener is unaware that the table exists?  At any rate, how do I get the listener to respond to a click on the generated link?

Comment: Your guess is correct, and there's a couple ways to handle it. One would be to put the listner on the parent `#hidden-contrib-id` and have it handle the changes on it's child elements since `hidden-contrib-id` is there when your page loads the listeners are still there despite what changes inside ot it. Or you can wrap your listeners in a function and re-attach them to the dynamic elements after you update them `$('#checksEnteredContainer').html(buildTable(result)); // attach various listeners here` Or you could have a listener to listen for changes and attach listeners on updates, etc.

Comment: oh, duh... `.remove_check` doesn't exist when the listener is executed.  So I would need to attach it to `#checksEnteredContainer`.  Now to check out the link provided above...

Comment: :facepalm:  `$('.remove_check').on('click', function() {` vs `$(document).on('click','.remove_check', function() {`  Thanks to the referenced link.  Won't be making that mistake again.

Answer (score -1):

```
 // Insted of this click, you can use below click function 

$('.remove_check').on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).data('contribution-id'));
  });


  $(document).on('click','.remove_check', function() {
             alert($(this).data('contribution-id'));
        });
```

Note :- 
use event delegation for dynamically created elements.

For more detail go [here](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score -1):

Your guess is correct, of course. You can ...

- delay the addition of the listener with `setTimeout`
- use `onclick` to trigger the funtion
- add the listener in the success function of the ajax request

All of these should make the listener work.